# How get information about devices in LAN network at cocoa

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, networking

I need to get list of devices(printers, laptops, ...) and information(ip, MAC, name) for each device at iPhone.
I have no idea how. Could anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html).